# Error when I try to print number

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086

I learn assembly 8086.

I have this code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
 num db 10111111b
 itr db 7 ;iterations
.code
 mov ax, @data
 mov ds, ax

 mov cl,0 ;rolls counter
 mov ch,0 ;zero counter 

next:                  
 rol num, 1
 jnc isZero
 inc cl
 cmp cl, itr
 je  stop
 jmp next              

isZero: 
  inc ch
jmp next     

stop:
  mov cl,0 
  add cx, 48

  mov ah, 9
  mov dx, cx
  int 21h


 .exit
end
```

The code above counts zero digits in *num* variable ,when zero is detected `ch` register increased by one. The code works fine.

I have a problem when I try to print the result on the screen.

On this row:

```
int 21h
```

I get this error:

```
INT 21h, AH=09h - 
address: 07330
byte 24h not found after 2000 bytes.
; correct example of INT 21h/9h:
mov dx, offset msg
mov ah, 9
int 21h
ret
msg db "Hello$"
```

Any idea why I get the above error? And how to fix it?

Comment: Your code stores numeric data in register `dx`. Instead, `dx` should be holding the address of a string of ASCII codes stored in memory, terminated by `$`. The error message says it all, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've stored the result in `CH`, and because the test data is a mere byte the count of zero bits will vary from 0 to 8. Displaying then is easy if you use another DOS output function.

```
add ch, 48
mov dl, ch
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
```

Alternatively define `Result db " $"` and use:

```
add ch, 48
mov Result, ch
mov ah, 09h
mov dx, offset Result
int 21h
```